# Merging multiple rows from one table into multiple colums in a SQL Query Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am pulling a basic query for a new report and have come across this little snag.

I have two tables `Buildings` (B) and `Pictures` (P) the key that is in both is the BuildingNumber. I have a simple Inner join between the two tables. The problem that I am having is that I have 183 buildings that are in B, but there are multiple pictures for each building, and the number of pictures is not consistent for each building. So when I get the result set, it is returning about 260 rows. What I would like to do is return just one row for each building and have a column for each picture associated with that building. Keep in mind that I do not have the rights to alter or create tables.

My Data is like this:

Building Table (B):

```
BuildingNumber   BldgName   Floors   SqFt

  0001           Science       5     50000
  0002           Engineering   4     40000
```

Picture Table (P):

```
BuildingNumber     PictureURL

   0001                URL1
   0001                URL2
   0001                URL3  
   0002                URL1 
   0002                URL2
```

So my desired result set it like this:

```
BuildingNumber   BldgName   Floors   SqFt   PictureURL1   PictureURL2   PictureURL3

    0001         Science        5     50000       URL1        URL2         URL3
    0002         Engineering    4     40000       URL1        URL2          NULL
```

Comment: To clarify the question, you want a dynamic number of columns at the end of the row?

Comment: Correct. I have no real idea of how many pictures there are for each building.

Comment: Better is to execute 2 queries and in your program you can match the pictures ande the buildings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result, this function converts your rows of data into columns.

If you have a limited number of `PictureURLs` for each building, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select BuildingNumber, bldgname, floors, sqft,
  PictureURL1, PictureURL2, PictureURL3
from
(
  select b.BuildingNumber, b.bldgname, b.floors, b.sqft,
    p.PictureURL,
    col = 'PictureURL'+
            cast(row_number() over(partition by b.BuildingNumber
                                    order by b.BuildingNumber) as varchar(10))
  from building b
  inner join picture p
    on b.BuildingNumber = p.BuildingNumber
) d
pivot
(
  max(PictureURL)
  for col in (PictureURL1, PictureURL2, PictureURL3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/008f42/6). But if you have an unknown number of values, then you will have to look at using dynamic SQL.  This will create a sql string that will be executed to get the final result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('PictureURL'+
                                                      cast(row_number() over(partition by BuildingNumber
                                                                              order by BuildingNumber) as varchar(10))) 
                    from Picture
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT BuildingNumber, bldgname, floors, sqft,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select b.BuildingNumber, b.bldgname, b.floors, b.sqft,
                p.PictureURL,
                col = ''PictureURL''+
                        cast(row_number() over(partition by b.BuildingNumber
                                                order by b.BuildingNumber) as varchar(10))
              from building b
              inner join picture p
                on b.BuildingNumber = p.BuildingNumber
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(PictureURL)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/008f42/7). Both give a result:

```
| BUILDINGNUMBER |    BLDGNAME | FLOORS |  SQFT | PICTUREURL1 | PICTUREURL2 | PICTUREURL3 |
|              1 |     Science |      5 | 50000 |        URL1 |        URL2 |        URL3 |
|              2 | Engineering |      4 | 40000 |        URL1 |        URL2 |      (null) |
```

Comment: Are the single quotes supposed to be there? I tried with and without, but still not getting the result set.

Comment: @Jake Which single quotes?

Comment: To Clarify, in front of the SELECT after the "Set @query = "

Comment: @Jake The set query is creating a sql string so the single quotes are required to be there.

Comment: Thank you sir. I really appreciate your help on this. I got the second query to run and pull all the relevant data that I needed.